# Is it possible to jump to the closing bracket of any expression, not just a scope in IntelliJ?

Tags: visual-studio, scope, intellij-idea, shortcut

So, I can jump to the start and end of a scope in IntelliJ.
But, I would also like to be able to jump between the round brackets -  '(' and ')', like I do in VS.

Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut because this feature doesn't exist yet, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12068).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably aware of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and how they do not work for round brackets.

You may be able to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> combinations to your benefit, though.